# How to disable texture wrapping caused by PVRTC compression?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, pvrtc

When I compress texture with PVRCT I can see artefacts in my texture - it is being wrapped.

**Source:**

[image: source texture]

**Result** *(you can see brown line on the left even and it shouldn't be there; ignore the dark border around - it makes it easier to see the problem)*.

[image: PVRTC compressed texture]

Is there a way to disable that wrapping? I've read in PVRTexTool manual suggestion that I should add borders in order to avoid this issue, but my problem is that I need to keep my texture power-of-two and I can not scale it down (in order to fit borders), because that would mean loosing quality.

Maybe there is another PVRTC compression tool that doesn't cause this problem? Or could someone explain why no one fixed it: is decompression happening on hardware and it's "implemented" that way there?

Comment: Is the above part of a texture atlas?    Also, does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044674/is-there-any-tool-to-split-a-pvr-texture-into-a-set-of-tiles/6046986#6046986) help as an explanation?

Comment: No, it's not texture atlas - that wouldn't be a problem at all - I could simply pad each texture in the atlas. I've read your answer again. Yes, that does help. I didn't know that PVRTC that information is shared between adjacent blocks, which implies that the problem is not in a compression tool, but in format and implementation (of software and hardware too). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Given that it's not part of a texture atlas, is the brown edge on the right-hand side strictly necessary? If that (or even just a couple of the right most columns of pixels) could be replaced with something similar to the left part of the image, it'd look a lot better. (As I said in the other answer, PVRTC2 addresses all this but apart from a few Android devices and (I think) the PSVita, it's not exposed on many systems)

Comment: Yes, I can fix this particular case by filling left side by something that matches colors on the right side. But in other cases I need both left and right sides as they are and they can have quite different colors (light vs dark shadows) and it results in seems between tiles. I picked this texture because it clearly demonstrates the problem. Thanks again!